# Swagger is not showing 'Authorize' icon

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-2.0

I have an API Project which uses Swagger.

I am using .NET Core Web API (version 6)

Without Authorization, I can not test my end points. I can use POSTMAN but would prefer using Swagger.

[image: missing authorize button]

Comment: what framework are you suing for your API?

Comment: .NET Core 6 Web API

Comment: I did not use .NET. However, I have encountered the same issue with spring boot. Swagger was working fine until I added the spring security dependency, which required authentication. I had to disable from spring security configurations.

Comment: ensure your `.MapSwagger()` or other endpoint registration is _before_ the authorization middleware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` package to `API` project. Add the below configuration for to `Program` class

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(option =>
{
    option.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Demo API", Version = "v1" });
    option.AddSecurityDefinition(
        "Bearer",
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Description = "Please enter a valid token",
            Name = "Authorization",
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
            BearerFormat = "JWT",
            Scheme = "Bearer"
        }
    );
    option.AddSecurityRequirement(
        new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
        {
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Reference = new OpenApiReference
                    {
                        Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                        Id = "Bearer"
                    }
                },
                new string[] { }
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Now you can see the `Authorize` option on swagger home page and authorization works if you are using `jwt` tokens.

For more info refer [this](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3650668/implement-authorization-for-swagger-in-aspnet-core-6.html) blog